# Uncaught TypeError: Promise.reject is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I had a problem;

```
const p4 = new Promise.reject("Error");
```

or

```
const p4 = new Promise.resolve("Sucess");
```

I get such an error when defining;

> Uncaught TypeError: Promise.reject is not a constructor

There shouldn't be any errors.

Comment: Remove the `new` keyword. Although raising a promise you immediately reject with no chained handlers is a rather odd thing to be doing - I'm assuming this is just an excerpt of your actual logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can fix the error. The issue is with the new keyword.

`Promise.reject` is a static methods rejects Promises directly so you should not use the `new` keyword with them.

here is [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) of Promises